# Loop sucessivos em Assembly usando Gcc e IAS

Tags: assembly

Estou estudando Assembly porem estou com muita dificuldade, tenho que resolver um exercício porem não entendi o que fazer.
"Fazer um loop para subtrações sucessivas ate negativo."
Estou usando o Gcc do Linux e IAS.
Alguém pode me ajudar

Comment: Qual parte vc nao entendeu?

Comment: tenho que indicar as posições de memória e acessar com o código. Os dois ´números iniciais serão fornecidos, e a subtração será sucessivas ate que um fique negativo. M(A) -M(B). não entendi como fazer.

Comment: Pega um numero qualquer e vai subtraindo até ficar negativo.

Comment: Sim vou fornecer 2 números e o programa fica em loop enquanto for >= 0